# Convert an old lazy sequence to a new lazy sequence via application of univariate function

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation

suppose in clojure I have a lazy sequence (a b c d .....) and suppose that I have a univariate function f(x). How would I transform the old lazy sequence into a new lazy sequence (f(a) f(b) ....). i.e. I seek the transformation. Thanks :

```
(a b ....) [lazy] -> (f(a) f(b) ....) [also lazy]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`map` does everything you need. It preserves the "laziness" of sequences that you apply it to.

```
(map f old-lazy-sequence)
=> [new-lazy-sequence]
```

Example with infinite ranges:

```
(take 5 
  (map (partial * 2) 
       (range)))
=> (0 2 4 6 8)
```